# Solving a BVP with the wave equation by using the Laplace Transform

Tags: partial-differential-equations, laplace-transform, boundary-value-problem, wave-equation

What follows is an example on how to solve a BVP using the Laplace Transform. I will copy and paste the example and its solution from the book that I am using and then I will ask my question.

[image: BVP]

[image: Solution]

When finding $U(x,s)$ you first find the general solution to the associated homogeneous equation $\frac{d^2U}{dx^2}-s^2U=0$. To me it seems like the book is assuming that $s\neq0$, since $U_c(x,0)=c_1+xc_2$. I was wondering if you see a reason why $s$ cannot be $0$.